# Not receiving the reversed text in java file handling

Tags: java, file, exception

I am trying to create a new file that write a string to a file. Then , I read that file and reverse the text in the file and store the text in my new file.

> This is my codes

```
package OpenFile;



import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class inversetext {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        try {
            ObjectOutputStream file = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("testio.txt"));
            file.writeUTF("ABCDEFHIJK");

            file.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("File cannot be created");
        }


        try {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("testio.txt"));
            ObjectOutputStream newfile = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("reverse.txt"));

            while (input.hasNextLine()){
                String read = input.nextLine();

                for (int x= read.length()-1 ; x>=0 ;x--){
                    newfile.write(read.charAt(x));
                }

            
            }

            newfile.close();
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("File cannot write");
        }
    }
}
```

> However , I am not receiving the intended output.

This is how my testio.txt file looks like:

```
¬í w
 ABCDEFGHIJK
```

But this is how my reverse.txt file looks like:

```
Ԁቷշ䮬䥊䝈䕆䍄䅂
```

So , my question is:Why am I not getting the reverse text but I got all this characters?

Comment: You're trying to read a serialized value like it was a line-oriented text file? Of course that's not going to work well.

Comment: Use `ObjectInputStream` to read data created by `ObjectOutputStream`

Comment: And `BufferedReader`/`BufferedWriter` for text.

Comment: I see , thank you

Comment: I don't know.. it is all Chinese to me.